# Vue.js life-cycle hook for v-cloak

Tags: javascript, highcharts, vue.js

I'm working on a project where [v-cloak](https://vuejs.org/api/#v-cloak) is styled with `display: none`, and decorates the body. This means everything is hidden until the Vue instance is ready.

I've made a component that inserts a chart (using [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)). The component is inserted on `ready`, yet the chart does not display correctly.

Here is a [jsfiddle demonstrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/sgpm367h/).

I could solve the problem by polling until the element is displayed, but is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Vue's nextTick to inject the chart, this will guarantee that the DOM is ready to be updated:

```
ready: function() {
  this.$nextTick(function() {
        this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart(this.opts);
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/hje7bqrn/